# Using viper to read config from envfile

Tags: go, viper-go

I don't really understand how viper works.
This is my code:

configuration.go

```
var Config *Configuration

type ServerConfiguration struct {
    Port string
}

type Configuration struct {
    Server   ServerConfiguration
}

func Init() {
    var configuration *Configuration
    viper.SetConfigFile(".env")
    viper.AutomaticEnv()
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error reading config file, %s", err)
    }

    err := viper.Unmarshal(&configuration)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to decode into struct, %v", err)
    }

    Config = configuration
}

func GetConfig() *Configuration {
    return Config
}
```

.env
`SERVER_PORT=:4747`

The problem is that Unmarshal does not work
When I use for example configuration.Server.Port it's empty

Comment: I would comment, but my reputation is not high enough. Your code worked on my machine. I would recommend testing viper.Get(FullName) on your values to see if you can get them. As for using _ nested variables inside the .env, use a new viper instance: v := viper.NewWithOptions(viper.KeyDelimiter("_"))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[spf13/viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) predominantly uses [mapstructure](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure?tab=doc) package to convert between one native Go type to another i.e. when un-marshaling. The package internally uses `map[string]interface{}` type to store your config (see [viper.go - L1327](https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/master/viper.go#L1327)). After that depending on the config type (your case being `env`), viper calls the right parsing package to store your config values. For envfile type, it uses [subosito/gotenv](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/subosito/gotenv?tab=doc) to put in the above said map type (see [viper.go - L1501](https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/3826be313591f83193f048520482a7b3cf17d506/viper.go#L1501))

The crux of your problem is how to make viper unmarshal this config in a map to a struct of your choice. This is where the mapstructure package comes in, to unmarshal the map into a nested structure of you have defined. At this point you are left with two options

1. Unmarshal the config as a `map[string]interface{}` type, and later put in the appropriate structure using mapstructure
2. Use the [DecodeHookFunc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure?tab=doc#DecodeHookFunc) as a 2nd argument to your method to unmarshal your config (See [viper.go - L904](https://github.com/spf13/viper/blob/master/viper.go#L904))

For the sake of simplicity reasons you can do one, which according to a trivial example I've reproduced with your example can be done below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

type ServerConfiguration struct {
    Port string `mapstructure:"server_port"`
}

type Configuration struct {
    Server ServerConfiguration `mapstructure:",squash"`
}

func main() {
    var result map[string]interface{}
    var config Configuration
    viper.SetConfigFile(".env")
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading config file, %s", err)
    }

    err := viper.Unmarshal(&result)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to decode into map, %v", err)
    }

    decErr := mapstructure.Decode(result, &config)

    if decErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("error decoding")
    }

    fmt.Printf("config:%+v\n", config)
}
```

You can make this working example customized depending on your actual use case. More information about the mapstructure `squash` tags for embedded structure can be found [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure?tab=doc#hdr-Embedded_Structs_and_Squashing)